# Multi dimensional array Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating 3 dimensional array but something goes wrong

```js
var bucket =[0];
var choose = [[],[]];
var x = 0;
$.each($('.bucket'), function() {
    bucket[x] = [choose[0], []];
    for (var i=0; i<$(this).find('.choose').length; i++) {
        choose[i][0] = $(this).find('.serie').val();
        choose[i][1] = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
        choose[i][2] = $(this).find('.type').val();
        choose[i][3] = $(this).find('.totali').val();
    }; // end for
    x++;
}); // end each buckets
console.log(choose);
```

and console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

What's wrong?

Comment: Because you try to reference `choose[0]`. You need to define it with something

Comment: U didn't define bucket array

Comment: What does `$(this).find('.choose').length` return? You only defined two elements inside `choose`. So if `i === 2`, you trying to set `choose[2]`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I tryed choose=[[0],[0]] and nothing really changed

Comment: See my comment above yours.

Answer (score 1):

The variable bucket hasn't been initialized and you're trying to access position x=0. Use `var bucket = [];` before accessing to position 0.